# WIll EOL releases no longer be archived?

Tags: release-management

According to this [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/184942) question, EOL releases are archived to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com.

But currently, I cannot see Ubuntu 12.10 and Ubuntu 13.04 to be available on this website, while all others(since 4.10) are available, as you can see in the screenshot below

[image]

So has canonical and/or Ubuntu devel-teams decided not to archive EOL releases any more?
or is it work to be done?

Comment: Raring is there: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/. Wonder about Quantal too.

Comment: @Danatela But it's not shown here http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They don't transfer EOL immediately to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com, they keep them on http://releases.ubuntu.com or sometimes http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/ for a while. The cdimage one seems to get cleared faster. I don't know how this time period is determined or it's length it's just something I've noticed when downloading isos.

**Ubuntu 12.10 Page** = http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/

**Ubuntu 13.04 Page** = http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/

Remember their are also 3rd party mirrors sometimes available that may have older isos still available such as http://mirrors.nl.eu.kernel.org/ubuntu-releases/ which still has 12.10 here: http://mirrors.nl.eu.kernel.org/ubuntu-releases/12.10/

Comment: Fine with the iso's, but where are the packages? The repos must have been archived somewhere?

Comment: @RegisteredUser To my knowledge the apt repos are only on old-releases. You can also get some packages from security.ubuntu.com as seen here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/amd64/vlc-plugin-notify/download . You can manually download packages from 3rd party mirrors listed on packages.ubuntu.com

Comment: @RegisteredUser are you familiar with the process of updating your apt sources.list to use old-releases.ubuntu.com?

Comment: yes I'm familiar. BTW I want to know the same thing. AFAIK packages are available on old.release but there are not there currently.

Comment: @RegisteredUser it seems they will move 13.04 only after 12.04 will become EOL.

Comment: @Danatela any sources?

Comment: You are right, they haven't moved it there yet. If you browse the address manually it's not valid for 12.10, but it is for 13.04. http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/ works, but http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/ gives 404. You can see the list here: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/

Comment: If you need an alternative repo to hold you over till the Ubunut ones are up some of the third party repos still work. I just installed vlc on 12.10 using the kernel.org repos. I found the mirror in this list http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/amd64/leafpad/download but there are others not listed here. The code I used was "deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted univers multiverse".

Comment: I added mirrors.kernel.org to a 12.10 system and installed one software. I also checked the `ubuntu-support-status` command which shows the following output

`You have 1522 packages (54.8%) supported until November 2015 (18m)

You have 728 packages (26.2%) that can not/no-longer be downloaded

You have 525 packages (18.9%) that are unsupported`

These are not archives though, they are just mirrors which have not removed 12.10 packages because they (probably) have enough space on there servers.

Comment: The answer still does not answer the main point, i.e weather Ubuntu-devel-teams and/or canonical have any plan to archive 12.10 and following EOL releases. If it will be done only after 12.04 will be EOL as @Danatela said, can anyone source this news?

Comment: @RegisteredUser there is another thing: 13.04 went eol BEFORE 12.10. Could be that for this 1 time they waited for 13.04 to go before moving 12.10.

Comment: 12.10 is still not there

Answer (score 0):

Quantal has now appeared in the old-releases.ubuntu.com mirror! Happy Days :)

[obsolete answer follows]
This week the main ubuntu mirror seemed to drop 12.10/quantal repository package pool altogether. Old-releases still has not picked it up, and like everyone else here, I'm struggling to find any information on future plans to do so (or not).

In the meantime, we found a repository that still contains *some* packages:
http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu.com/

Currently we can only confirm the **quantal** and **quantal-updates** distributions, with **main**, and **universe** sections for each, restricted and multiverse are there but fairly incomplete.

While this does not answer the question I thought I'd document my resolution while there is still some life in at least one repository:

**Mirror the repo locally**

Here's an example of doing it with debmirror - I'm behind a corporate firewall that only allows http/s (no rsync or ftp), and requires authentication so I've accounted for those restrictions in my options. You'll need about 87GB for binary packages for i386 and amd64 architectures combined (from memory, sync still in progress here). I would triple that if you need source packages too:

```
sudo apt-get install debmirror
sudo debmirror --progress --verbose --host=ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ \
 --method=http --proxy=http://user:pass@proxy:port --dist=quantal,quantal-updates \
 --section=main,universe --arch=i386,amd64 --nosource /path/to/local/mirror/
```

Hope that helps -

Comment: There was mention of rolling releases in between LTS's a couple of months back. A rolling release would kill the need for archives for non LTS. But I would assume all would stay the same up to when this is decided (though the 13.04 going EOL before 12.10 was a surprise :D )

Comment: While the rolling release would get you out of a bind, a stable package environment, particularly in a production environment, is by far the more manageable option