# No option to upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 13.10, upgrade

```
$ sudo apt-get update #Don't get any errors
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo update-manager -d
```

Ubuntu checks for updates, tells me my computer is up to date. But there are only two options now "Ok" and "Settings". According to [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade) and several other websites, there should be an option to upgrade it to 14.04, but I'm seeing none. How can I upgrade to 14.04?

Comment: @CharlesGreen I am not trying to install anything for my unsupported release. I just want to move to 14.04 from 13.10. I don't see how that question relates to mine. I followed the instructions to upgrade and an option that shows up in the screenshots of the official version don't show up in mine.

Comment: That `apt-get update` didn't throw any errors is a big red flag to me. It should.

Comment: @yayu [That question generally applies](http://askubuntu.com/q/91815) to doing a release upgrade out of an unsupported release), as well as to installing software on such a release. (Though [sometimes it's unnecessary](http://askubuntu.com/q/483906).) Have you tried adding the old-releases software sources there? If so, and you still have this problem, please edit your question with the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`. I agree with muru that it's strange you didn't get errors from the `update` action; you may have to [restore the default repositories](http://askubuntu.com/q/124017).

Comment: @EliahKagan I have upgraded to the newest version. I ended up taking a backup to my important programs on a vps and reinstalling from scratch, after I couldn't find a solution for a couple of hours.

Answer (score 3):

### Ubuntu Desktops 13.10 to 14.04 (Recommended)

You can easily upgrade over the network with the following procedure.

1. Run the **update-manager** application from the **Unity Dash** or a command line
2. In Update Manager, click the **Settings...** button, and enter your password to start the Software Sources application.
3. Select the sub menu **Updates** from the Software Sources application.
4. Confirm the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:" option is set to "For any new version", and change it if otherwise.
5. Close the Software Sources application and return to Update Manager.
6. In Update Manager, click the **Check** button to check for new updates.
7. If there are any updates to install, use the **Install Updates** button to install them, and press **Check** again after that is complete.
8. A message will appear informing you of the availability of the new release.
9. Click **Upgrade**.
10. Follow the on-screen instructions.