# Wily old release repositories

Tags: upgrade, package-management, updates, 15.10

I was following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/) on updating an EOL distribution. I want to upgrade from 15.10 (wily).

I am using `apt-get` rather than `aptitude` that is used in the guide. I added the `.list` sources file in my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.

when I run `sudo apt-get update` it tells me it is unable to fetch those packages. I investigated a bit and I can see [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/) that all the old releases are there except Wily. Is this an oversight or am I following an outdated guide?

Comment: Related http://askubuntu.com/questions/483906/will-eol-releases-no-longer-be-archived

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like `wily` has been moved.

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/

Answer (score 0):

- It is still in its place, it is not moved yet to `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/`

  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/

  You can follow regular release upgrade instructions